# User Explicitly for Windows Network Share

Tags: windows, windows-10, network-shares, smb

Is it possible to create a User that is exclusively used for Network Share?

Why don't I just use my account? It's because I want to be able to share the account with specific people, without fear of sharing my own password.

Why not just create a local account? It's because I don't want the account to access **anything** on the machine (including Program Files, etc.). If I were to create a local account, then anyone can log in to that account on the physical machine and access other stuff.

Comment: You can create users that don't have log on privileges.

Comment: @MichaelFrank Thanks for the comment. It pointed me to the right places for research and allowed me to come up with a solution.

Comment: No problem! I would have written an answer, but just a bit busy here at work at the moment. :) Glad you found your solution though!

Answer (score 2):

It appears there is no way to create a User that is explicitly for use with Network Share. However, it is possible to create a user and restrict their privileges (including the ability to log on locally).

1. Create the User using any method.
2. Open `mmc`. One way to do this is to use WIN+R and running `mmc`.
3. Add the Snap-In (CTRL+M) of Local Computer Policy.
4. Navigate to `Local Computer Policy/Computer Configuration/Windows Settings/Security Settings/Local Policies/User Rights Assignment`.
5. Find the Policy named `Deny log on locally` and double click to add user.

By default, access via Network is enabled for the `Everyone` Group. So, the user should be able to access network by default, regardless to what group they are in. Just make sure the user and its groups are not part of the `Deny access to this computer from the network` Policy.

Thanks to Michael Frank for pointing me in the right direction.
Did some research to come up with this solution (pretty new to administrating).

Thanks to grawity for pointing out my incorrect use of "Virtual" User.

Comment: "A user that does not actually exist, but instead is simulated through software" [makes zero sense](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TechnoBabble) – _all_ user accounts are simulated through software. And none of it matters here anyway. Your whole question basically said "I want a user _with fewer privileges_", and as in this answer you can do exactly that. Nothing "virtual" about it.

Comment: @grawity Thanks for the pointer. You are correct, using the word "privileges" definitely makes more sense than the word "virtual". I've updated both the question and the answer.

Comment: As a side note, you can remove a user from the "Users" group. They'll still be a member of "Everyone" and will therefore have read access to some of the drive, but won't have access to most of it and shouldn't have write access to almost anywhere except their profile. I haven't tried this, though.

Comment: @CBHacking I see, that is indeed an alternative.